# ODataProperties (System.Web.OData.Extensions - OData v4) Missing ''Model' Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

I am trying to create an instance of `ODataQueryContext` which requires an `EdmModel` reference. I am attempting to get the `Model` from `ODataProperties()` which is a method call off of the `HttpRequestMessage` object.

```
var orderBy = new OrderByQueryOption("ColumnName desc", new ODataQueryContext(Request.ODataProperties().Model, typeof(MyType)));
```

It seems that if I use the namespace `using System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions;` as opposed to `using System.Web.OData.Extensions;` the Model property is available from `ODataProperties()`. However, I am using the newer version (OData v4) namespaces, for other references in my program.

After doing some research I determined that with OData v4, they moved everything from `Web.Http.OData.*` namespaces, to `Web.OData.*` namespaces. I am assuming that I need to be consistent in using either the new or old namespaces, and I was not successful attempting to mix them.

Does anyone know how to get the `Model` property from `ODataProperties()` without using the older `Web.Http.OData` namespaces?

Answer (score 9):

To anyone still having trouble with this (I ended-up here from a MS OData tutorial) `request.ODataProperties().Model` has changed to `request.GetModel()` ( HttpRequestMessageExtensions in namespace Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions in assembly Microsoft.AspNet.OData). Also `request.ODataProperties().PathHandler` has changed to `request.GetPathHandler()`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. All the documentation I have found so far talks about the old methods, your post is a life saver.

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET Core 3.1, package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData, most values under `Request.ODataProperties()` are now under `Request.ODataFeature()`.

Answer (score 0):

ODataProperties().Model from OData on github